ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0. Android Studio, flutter
The entire error code:
What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform UsbSerial-6.1.0.aar (com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
Could not find UsbSerial-6.1.0.aar (com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jitpack.io/com/github/felHR85/UsbSerial/6.1.0/UsbSerial-6.1.0.aar
https://jitpack.io/com/github/felHR85/UsbSerial/6.1.0/UsbSerial-6.1.0.jar

My gradle file:
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.application") ||
                    project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
                project.android {
                    compileSdkVersion 34
                    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

and app/gradle:
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    }
 
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    def flutterTargetSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion')
    if (flutterTargetSdkVersion == null) {
        flutterTargetSdkVersion = '30' // Установите значение по умолчанию, если необходимо
    }
    
    android {
        namespace "name"
        compileSdkVersion 34
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "name"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion flutterTargetSdkVersion.toInteger()
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
    
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.6.1-full'
        implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
    
        constraints {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
                because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
            }
        }
   }

I have added the following line to the gradle file:
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
I have also included maven:
    repositories {    
     google()     
     jcenter()     
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

version android studio - LadyBug
Also tried to change the JDK version and Android Studio itself, but nothing helped
i need help, please

That library has not been updated in over five years, so your first decision to make is: does it make sense to use an unsupported library like this?

it is used in the common project, alternatives are not available yet

Then fork the project and maintain your own copy.

@VladIslav was you able to fix the issue?

change the version you used in the implementation to earlier version - i used  6.0.3 - , if you have the same error you might uses a package that implements the version 6.1.0 -in my case it was "usb-serial-0.5.2" -, so you need to change the version in the package build gradle too,
go to your project on android studio => external libraries => Flutter plugins=> the package  ,and change the version from dependencies as you did with the build gradle file of your project

try to change on your pubspec.yaml
usb_serial:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jymden/usbserial.git
      ref: master

